# Caesar Cipher Code Flaw

Tags: c, string, algorithm, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have coded a Caesar cipher that seem to work in most tests but fails on a few cases. More on the test details are https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1

Basic info: The cipher only encrypts letters, symbols etc stay unencrypted.

Fails on this case:

```
90
!m-rB`-oN!.W`cLAcVbN/CqSoolII!SImji.!w/`Xu`uZa1TWPRq`uRBtok`xPT`lL-zPTc.BSRIhu..-!.!tcl!-U
62
```

Where 90 is n (characters in string), second line is string in array s, and 62 is k (amount of letter rotations)

Any insight into the flaw of my code will be highly appreciated

Code:

```
int main(){
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
char* s = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",s);
int k;
scanf("%d",&k);

if (k>26) {
    k%=26;
}

int rotation;
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
        if((s[i] + k) > 'z' ) {
            rotation = (s[i] - 26) + k;
            s[i] = rotation;
        } else {
            s[i] = s[i]+k;
        }

    } else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
        if((s[i] + k) >= 'Z' ) {
            rotation = (s[i] - 26) + k;
            s[i] = rotation;
        } else {
            s[i] = s[i]+k;
        }
    } 

}

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* does it fail on that case? Please be more specific.

Comment: Also, have you debugged? This is almost definitely just a "one off" indexing error.

Comment: It isn't the problem, but `scanf("%s",s);` is vulnerable to a buffer-overflow. The best way to make sure that you never do something like that in production code is to get in the habit of never doing something like that at all, even in toy problems.

Comment: Why `malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));` and not `malloc(n+1);`? It might be better to use `getchar()` in any case; `scanf("%s")` will stop at the first white space character and cause `scanf("%d",&k);` to fail. Also, `if (k>26) { k%=26; }` is wrong, should be `if (k>25) { k%=26; }` or just `k%=26;`. Instead of `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { printf("%c", s[i]); }`, how about `puts(s);`?

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman 
I'm no too sure why it fails on that case specificaly, I'm not really able to debug it as I'm doing it via the website and it wont show any results other than pass or fail. I will have to wait till I get home to build and see what errors I get

Comment: @JohnColeman also wth the scanf comment, you're right I should be getting into good habits thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, so I've figured it out.

```
Old Code:
 if((s[i] + k) >= 'Z' )
New Code:
 if((s[i] + k) > 'Z' )
```

It messed up when given a P(ascii 80), it should have stopped at Z(ascii 90) but instead did this calculation:

```
s[i] - 26 + k  = 64
  80 - 26 + 10 = 64 (ascii for @) and thus '@' was returned instead of Z
```